# Using Interfaces and Polymorphism

Tags: c#

First time poster just learning c#.  I've been playing around with a problem the past few days, failing, googling, retrying, learning.  But now wanted to appeal to anyone who can help with a little guidance.  The basic idea is working with and around interfaces.

Just writing this up for illustrative purposes... Suppose I have a Zoo Exhibit.  An exhibit contains animals. I want to put each animal in a cage and the function to put an animal in a cage is identical for all animals.  So to do that I will define a common interface, IAnimal, for all animals.

```
public class ZooExhibit {

    public List<IAnimal> animalList;

    public ZooExhibit(){
        animalList = new List<IAnimal> ();
    }

    public void AddAnimal(IAnimal animal){
        animalList.Add (animal);
    }

    public void CageAnimals(){
        foreach (IAnimal a in animalList){
            a.PutInCage();
        }
    }
```

}

IAnimal looks like:

```
public interface IAnimal {
    int CageNumber { get; set; }
    void PutInCage ();
}
```

If I want a Monkey exhibit I could write something like:

```
public class Zoo {

    public ZooExhibit monkeyExhibit;

    public CreateExhibit(){
        monkeyExhibit = new ZooExhibit();
        monkeyExhibit.AddAnimal(new Monkey());
        monkeyExhibit.AddAnimal(new Monkey());
        monkeyExhibit.AddAnimal(new Monkey());
        monkeyExhibit.CageAnimal();
    }

}
```

So the PutInCage() code takes an object of IAnimal and puts it in a cage. PutInCage() also records the CageNumber that each animal is located in and is a property that can be accessed through the IAnimal interface.

Now here is my problem.  Each animal has different properties.  They all have CageNumber, but the monkey may have the property "Height" and Elephant may have "Weight" and a Tiger may have "Color".  So we can put the animals in cages, but since they are in the IAnimal interface we can only get the Cage number although I may be interested in getting and setting different properties down the line depending on the animal in the cage.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the general direction to go?  Am I totally misunderstanding where to use interfaces? Would I just need to make a function per animal?  Also, is there a keyword I should be thinking about a little more in addressing this problem?

Thanks.  I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: The first half of your question is clear, but the second half, not so much.  It's unclear when you need the more specific properties, and when you don't. You'd have to provide a more concrete example of what you need.  As a result, you can expect a diversity of vague answers.

Comment: Well you can do things like `var monkeys = animalList.OfType<Monkey>();` or loop through the list and say `if(animal is Monkey) { var monkey = animal as Monkey; ... }`

Comment: @Eonasdan "Make me a milkshake", you mean? OP: You can have methods of IAnimal that each of its implementors implements in its own unique way; that can be very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion originates from the bad example case. Technically you know what an interface is and how to implement it but you made up an example that does not help you understand how interfaces could be helpful.

In the example case, plain inheritance would be more appropriate, an animal having a nullable cage number. If it is assigned the animal is caged.

You would use an interface if the exhibit would not just have animals on display but also cars and paintings. Then you would have different types, having different ancestors. Those would not fit in a single inheritance tree. Yet you need common behavior or properties (usually just behavior). That is where interfaces come in and where they are useful.

Cagability is entirely animal related so it would be pointless to have an interface for that, the cagability can be implemented just fine in the Animal base class. But now think of Selling an item, the money you paid to aquire the exhibit item or the money you would charge people to have a look. Those would call for an interface IDisplayItem or IExhibitItem.

An interface lets you super-type different classes. In this case animals, cars and paintings.

Answer (score 0):

you are kind of on the right track.

The concept of caging should be separated out

```
class Cage
{ 
   public int Number { get; set; }
   public List<IAnimal> Animals { get; set;} = new List<IAnimal>();
   public Cage Lockup(IAnimal animal) { Animals.Add(animal); return this;}
}
```

then you can go for something like

```
public class Zoo
{
   List<Cage> Cages = new List<Cage>()
   public Cage AddCage(int number) 
   {
     var cage = new Cage(){Number = number}
     Cages.Add(cage);
     return cage; 
   }

}


    Zoo.AddCage(1).Lockup(new Sheep()).Lockup(new Lion()).CageFight();
```

But now you need to think about how you want to generically handle animals with different attributes.

One option is you have a generic concept for those attibutes, and you perhaps go IAnimal.Stats  which returns a list of stats about each animal.

Another option is each animal knows how to display itself.

Another option is to use something like the visitor pattern to recover the specific type to do specfic things with each animal

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this to be reusable and more generic behavior, you want to identify the "common" behavior and **that** is what you **abstract**. So, based on your post: "I want to put each animal *in a cage* and the *function to put an animal in a cage* is identical for all animals." That is the behavior you are trying to abstract. You want something like ICageable. You want your concrete classes and dependent classes to mutually depend on the *abstraction*.

If you think of Class A depending on Class B, it's more reusable and decoupled for Class A to depend on interface C and for Class B to implement interface C.

If this doesn't make sense, let me know and I can provide more concrete code examples. Basically, you're usually after ISomethingable.

I recommend you read up on the Open/Closed Principle and the SOLID principles in general.

Comment: actually this violates OCP,  if you give Monkey ICageable, you've had to change Monkey to give it that ability,  But you should be able to cage Monkeys without having to change them.  ie, Monkeys should be Closed to change but open to be caged :)

Comment: This gets more obvious when you change your zoo around so you don't cage monkeys anymore but have free roaming animals.

Comment: I have to disagree actually. You don't "give" interfaces, and per the OP's request, this would suffice. I provided SOLID as recommended or suggested reading since I don't agree with dogma, but I don't see how this violates OCP.

Comment: Interfaces become part of the type, part of its contract.   If a Monkey wasn't ICageable, and you wanted to introduce caging  functionality.  You shouldn't need to change Monkey at all.  Monkey could be sealed in a Library with no need for its type to change.

Comment: I have to disagree again. I think this is way overcomplicating the OP's example, but if you need caged and free roaming monkeys, you can create interfaces for those or a common interface (or base class) for shared behavior. The whole point to this is to have both your concrete classes and implementers of interfaces depend on abstractions rather than hard dependency (coupling) between the two.

Comment: No, I think this is bad advice,  his IAnimal concept is way better.  Having a concept of Caging IAnimals is easy then, and also FreeRoaming IAnimals is easy.....  or   even  ClassifyGoodForEating IAnimal.    Meaning Monkey/IAnimal is closed, no need to change it for any of these cases, but super extensible for whatever other uses of IAnimal you may come up with.

Comment: So... in this world of highly extensible Animals you describe, where ALL Animals implement the Layer Supertype you're describing (https://www.sitepoint.com/the-layer-supertype-pattern-encapsulating-common-implementation-in-multi-tiered-systems/) how exactly are they extensible and not extremely coupled to their interface? They all have to implement a Caged method. Liskov much?

Comment: And I realize it's not technically a Layer Supertype since it's not a base class, but it's the same idea. Not all animals should be caged, that's inhumane.

Comment: no, none of them should impliment cage, Caging is done on the exhibit not the Animal in the OPs question.

Comment: oh, but he has caging on IAnimal, which shouldn't live there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123779/discussion-between-captray-and-keith-nicholas).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know about [is and as operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx).

Basically, you can iterate over your collection of animals and if you need to get some specific properties you can use those operators to cast and handle the target object accordingly.

```
IEnumerable<IAnimal> animalList = new List<IAnimal>();
            foreach (IAnimal a in animalList)
            {
                a.PutInCage();

                //if it's a monkey get its height
                if (a is Monkey)
                {
                    var monkey = (Monkey)a; //cast is safe here because you ensure it's a money in the if statement.
                    Show(monkey.Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    //try to get it as an elephant 
                    var elephant = a as Elephant;
                    if (elephant != null)
                        Show(elephant.Weight);
                }
            }
```

As you can see, you can use `is` to avoid getting a null reference exception by asking first if the target object is o a given type. On the other hand, you use `as` to try the cast operation, but if the object is not of the given type, you will get a null object, so you must check for null.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the problem with this approach, which is sometimes useful, is that you end up with code with a lot of conditionals having to know about all your subtypes.

Comment: Agree with @KeithNicholas here. Is and Of checking leads to switch statements where you should be using Strategy patterns or something of that ilk.

Comment: I agree @KeithNicholas that if you have a big hierarchy of types, it may soon become hard to maintain, but I think it's worth it to recommend the OP to know about the basic operators given he's starting with C#.

Comment: Agreeing with @KeithNicholas, here's the [code smell](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) reference.

Comment: @TomBlodget, thanks for the comment, but the link you give applies when we can abstract the behavior right? How would you handle the case when you need access to some specific property / method in the NorwegianBlue brid for instance?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need generics.

Try this:

```
public class ZooExhibit<A> where A : IAnimal
{
    public List<A> animalList;

    public ZooExhibit()
    {
        animalList = new List<A>();
    }

    public void AddAnimal(A animal)
    {
        animalList.Add(animal);
    }

    public void CageAnimals()
    {
        foreach (A a in animalList)
        {
            a.PutInCage();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public class Zoo
{
    public ZooExhibit<Monkey> monkeyExhibit;

    public void CreateExhibit()
    {
        monkeyExhibit = new ZooExhibit<Monkey>();
        monkeyExhibit.AddAnimal(new Monkey());
        monkeyExhibit.AddAnimal(new Monkey());
        monkeyExhibit.AddAnimal(new Monkey());
        monkeyExhibit.CageAnimals();
    }
}
```

Now `monkeyExhibit.animalList` will be a strongly-typed list of `Monkey`.